# Assigning values to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need help with another method to assign values to the array. I provided the code that needs to be fixed. I am reading from a text file and within the text file, I need to sort out between c and s. The text file includes numbers and names.
The text file looks like this:

```
7623, S, Jones, Phyllis, 2000.00, 0 
7623, C, Jones, Phyllis, 1200.00, 2
8729, S, Smith, Cletus, 1000.00, 1
8729, C, Smith, Cletus, 1700.00, 0
7321, S, Booth, Betty, 4500.00, 2
3242, C, Seybright, Sam, 4612.00, 0
3242, S, Seybright, Sam, 100.00, 3
9823, S, Blu, Oscar, 234.00, 2
9823, C, Blu, Oscar, 2345.00, 0
2341, S, Grief, Sally, 12373.12, 1
2341, C, Grief, Sally, 5421.12, 2
8321, S, Matchel, Jacues, 2314.00, 0
8321, C, Matchel, Jacues, 56233.00, 0
```

The code below (having issues with the if statement):

```
try {
    FileReader inputValues = new FileReader("PRJ2Accounts.txt");
    BufferedReader holdValues = new BufferedReader(inputValues);
    while ((line = holdValues.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(",");
        Account account = null;
        if (values[1].equals("S")) {
            account = new Account(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], Double.parseDouble(values[4].trim()), Integer.parseInt(values[5].trim()));
        }
        if (values[1].equals("C")) {
            account = new Account(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], Double.parseDouble(values[4].trim()), Integer.parseInt(values[5].trim()));
        }
        for (String str1 : values) {
            System.out.print(str1 + " ");
            aryNewFile[lineCount][fieldCount] = str1;
            fieldCount++;
            fieldTotal++;
        } 
        lineCount++;
        fieldCount = 0;
        System.out.println(" ");
    } 
}
```

Comment: *having issues with the if statement* What issues are you having?

Comment: Please explain what *having issues with the if statement* really means?

Comment: Also why do both `if-statements` do the same thing?

Comment: I need to use another method to assign values to the array

Comment: I did if-statement because I need to differentiate between c and s

Comment: So you basically want to make the `if-statement` a method?

Comment: If I don't need to then no

Comment: I would also like to reiterate @GBlodgett question - you say that you need to differentiate between C and S, but you do the **exact same thing** in each case.

Comment: @Don please use the @ symbol to ping users so we can tell who you're responding to

Comment: @EJoshuaS so I can just remove the if statement and just have one statement that lists out the array?

Comment: @Don If the only possible values are `C` and `S` and you do the exact same thing in both cases, then yes, you can just get rid of the if statement completely - you only need to use an `if` statement if you actually do something different depending on what the value is.

Comment: I'm still confused what you are asking. Could you please clarify your problem?

Comment: @GBlodgett I need a different way to write the method to assign values to the array starting from the first if statement

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do

```
if (values[1].equals(" S"))
```

and

```
if (values[1].equals(" C"))
```

because your file seems to have whitespace after the comma.
An even better method would be just checking of values[1] *contains* "C" or "S"

Comment: Imho `line.split(",\\s*")` would be preferable to your solution.

Comment: totally right. Mine wasn't really failsafe. That's why I hinted on using contains()